# Rails geocoding only allowing one attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, maps, location, geocoding

I am trying to get the latitude and longitude values for two different values. These are set in the attributes `start` and `end` in my Mileage model.

```
geocoded_by :end, :latitude  => :latitude, :longitude => :longitude
geocoded_by :start, :latitude  => :start_lat, :longitude => :start_lon
```

I have the following attributes in my Mileage model:

```
start
start_lat
start_long
end
latitude
longitude
```

Depending on which `geocoded_by` line is at the top of the Mileage model, only one of the attributes is geocoded. Is there a way of making both attributes get processed by the geocoder [gem](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is no.

But its not hard to roll your own solution. Basically geocoded_by: sets up a simple way to geocode an address lat/long from a callback with a handful of options (lat/long column name, etc).

There's a utility method for looking up the lat/lng of an address:

```
Geocoder.coordinates(the_start_address)
     => [42.700149, -74.922767]
```

so you can use the geocoded_by: method to handle the end lat/long in your example and then do something like

```
before_save :geocode_the_start_address

def geocode_the_start_address
  coords = Geocoder.coordinates(self.start)
  self.start_lat = coords[0]
  self.start_long = coords[1]
end
```

Honestly I'd name things more consistently myself -- start_address, end_address, start_lat, start_long, etc. And I'd also use a custom method for geocoding the start and end address instead of geocoded_by so the code is more consistent.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with John Paul, but I'd do it in an `after_save` - so, basically, have your `Milage` model perform geocoding on the start address on creation, then after creation has taken place (e.g. the geocoding has been performed on the start address and you have a valid start address), perform the geocoding on the end address using a separate callback.